# QGIS / "create grid" consumes far more memory on linux than on windows

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, linux, memory

I am using QGIS 3.10 both on windows and on Linux with the same RAM and CPU resources.
When running the tool "create grid" QGIS behaves strange on Linux: For a certain extent (~ 10x10km), when creating a grid with 20m-100m cell size, memory consuming doesn't go beyond ~2,5-3GB. With 15m cell size, the calculations seem to exponentiate a lot - and it takes up to 30GB memory (not a steady increase, but rather abrupt) and it won't finish either. As my goal was initially a 10m grid - with this cellcize QGIS seems to crash a few minutes after running the tool, as memory goes up abruptly, however I don't any messages or warnings.

On windows, running the same tool with the same parameters behaves differently: for the 10m grid only half of the memory (max. 7-8GB from 16GB) is used - however I didn't let it complete as the area still seems to be too large.
I am splitting up the area for the calculation of the grid now, but I still wonder what causes this strange behavior on Linux ?

Comment: Please report this in the Issue section of the QGIS repository ( https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues ) to get help from the devs.